# Calculating integral over unit ball using co area formula

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, area, multiple-integral

> Calculate $\int_V\frac{1}{2+(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}dxdydz$, where $V=\{(x,y,z)|x^2+y^2+z^2\lt 1\}$ using the co area formula.

So I know that the formula is: $\int_V f dx$ = $\int_a^b\int_{M_c}\frac{f(x)}{|\nabla \phi(x)|}dS dc$, where $\phi:V\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\in C^1,\forall x: \nabla \phi(x)\neq 0,\phi(V)=(a,b)$ and $M_c=\{x=(x_1,...,x_n)\in V|\phi(x)=c,c\in(a,b)\}$.

My attempt -

So the difficult part here (for me) is to find the correct $\phi$. I thought about $\phi = x^2+y^2+z^2$ which is $\phi \in(0,1)$ but $\nabla \phi(0,0,0) =0$ so I cannot use it.

I also thought about $\phi = (x^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}$, but also here $\nabla \phi(0,0,0) =0$ so I cannot use it.

Other attempt was to use the function that we integrate - $\phi = \frac{1}{2+(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$ and here I know that $\nabla \phi \neq 0 \forall x$, but when I lower the dimension of the integral, which variable should be gone?(i.e., instead of $3$ dimensional, $dxdydz$, what should it be?)

Or perhaps, is there any better $\phi$ to use in this case?

Comment: Could you do change of variables to spherical coordinates, or is that antithetical to the exercise?

Comment: @LarryB.Well, it is kinda missing the point of the exercise which is the co area formula..

Comment: BTW how do you compute the gradient of a function?

Comment: @lcv $\nabla \phi (x,y,z) = (\phi_x,\phi_y,\phi_z)$

Comment: @lcv my notes from my class...

Comment: BTW I believe the coarea formula is valid more generally, but this version perfectly suffices for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint*.  If you pick

$$
\phi(\mathbf{x}) = \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}
$$

one has $\parallel \nabla \phi \parallel =1$ and the coarea formula becomes the formula for change of variables into spherical coordinates.

Comment: But then $\nabla \phi = (\frac{2x}{2\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}},\frac{2y}{2\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}},\frac{2z}{2\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}})$ and $\phi$ won't be $C^1$ as $\phi '$ is not defined in $(0,0,0)$...

Comment: BTW the end result, is the change of variable to spherical coordinates which is obviously allowed.

Comment: Ok, so what would be $M_c$ in that case?Would $c$ be our $0\lt r \lt 1$? and we remain with $\theta, \psi$?

Comment: It's the surface $r=c$, the surface of the sphere of radius $c$.

Comment: So after using the formula, and moving to spherical coordinates is it correct that the original integral equals to - $\int_0^1\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi\frac{1}{2+c^{\frac{3}{2}}}d\theta d\psi dc$?

Comment: Almost. $dS$ here is the surface element on the sphere of radius $c$, which is $dS = c^2 d\Omega$

Comment: Ugh, could you please ellaborate on that?

Comment: $dS$ is the surface element on $M_c$. By the way I was blind a few minutes ago. Of course $\nabla \phi$ is never zero (given that is a vector of norm 1).

Comment: Ah, the $c^2$ is from the Jacobian which we got from the change of variables?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87384/discussion-between-lcv-and-chikchak).